# How to use non system compiled libraries securely in ios

Tags: ios, static-libraries

How to use non system compiled libraries securely in iOS?.How to know non system library is secured or not?.

Comment: What do you mean “securely”? The only way to use non-system libraries in your app is to include them in your app bundle, and everything in the app bundle is cryptographically signed.

Comment: by using cocoapod you add them and use them. you can see its code too.